# Integration test file system dependent code in Java 7

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a situation where I am revising a Java 5 application and I would like to add additional tests (unit tests bordering on integration tests) to ensure that things are working correctly.  I need the application to be completely decoupled from the actual file systems provided by the operating system and I want to review the file access pattern and new file content afterwards.  I can run the unit tests in Java 7 or any other version in a fully controlled environment, I just need the final application to be Java 5 compatible, i.e. I need code like `new File(...)` to be what is worked with.

Can this be done without resorting to black magic (byte code manipulating mocking frameworks etc) for example by reconfiguring Java 7 or adding a suitable provider under the covers?

Comment: I doubt that's easily possible, as `File` is *very* hard-wired to work with the filesystem. Is OS-level "trickery" such as a [chroot environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

for sure you can mock your File class using `-Xbootclasspath` option. but then you have to consider licensing issues and imho it still won't let you do all required tests.

if file system operations are important for you application you should create a dedicated abstraction layer for file system access. it will somehow duplicates the java IO api but allows you to test how does your application interacts with IO api.

however if you are using some advanced techniques or you need high portability than it won't be enough for you. as Joachim said, File class is very dependent of the OS and filesystem. it will behave differently on linux, windows, different when you meet symlinks, acls, upercase names etc. in case you want to test this behavior, you will, in fact, have to test infrastructure not the application. therefore instead of unit tests you should think of integration tests on many different environments (maybe using virtual machines)